# Create xml with multiple root elements from txt file

Tags: python, xml

Im confused to convert content from `.xml` to `.txt`. Already I've dealt with conversion txt to xml, but problem with xml to txt seems to be harder.

App should take all values from child element and assign them into a list. The problem is that xml file has multiple roots elements (know that is invalid format) F.e: sample.xml looks as follows:

```
<row>
    <col>One</col>
    <col>Two</col>
    <col>Three</col>
</row>
<row>
    <col>John</col>
    <col>Mark</col>
    <col>Elise</col>
</row>
```

As the result sample.txt should looks as follows:

```
One Two Three
John Mark Elise
```

---

During writing this post i came with an idea but it looks ugly (especially with deleting col tag from line). Do you have any better ideas to get a values from child element `|col|`?

My code:

```
def convert_xml_to_txt(self):
        words_list = []
        with open(self.filename) as fxml:
            while True:
                line = fxml.readline()
                if line:
                    if line.startswith('<row'):
                        pass
                    else:
                        words_list.append(line[5:-7].strip()) #delete tags <col> from line
                else:
                    self.generate_txt_file(words_list)
                    break
```

Comment: Have you considered using the built in [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.html) library?

Comment: @Kendas: why consider that? It cannot handle such malformed XML data: "junk after document element: line 7, column 0".

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of libraries that you can use:
one is `untangle` and can be installed by `pip` like `pip install untangle`:

```
import untangle
obj = untangle.parse('path/to/file.xml')
```

or you can use `xmltodict` helpful library:

```
import xmltodict

with open('path/to/file.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```

For more information look at [This](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/xml/) link.